# Window for OpenVR with Vulkan needed?

Tags: c++, c++11, vulkan, openvr

When using vulkan and OpenVR for a game, do I need to create and open a window to make it work or can i just Submit the image to OpenVR?

Answer (score 1):

Technically you only need to submit the frames to the OpenVR compositor *but* it is strongly recommends you also display those same frames in a window.

The overhead from doing so is minimal, you are literally just displaying the same textures to a window as well as in the HMD.